# Understanding characters received from Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I have an Arduino board sending data through a serial port and a Python piece of code reading that data. The Arduino board just sends the temperature it reads from a TMP36 sensor and when I check the port using the port monitor that comes with the Arduino IDE I see this:

```
20.3
20.3
20.2
20.2
...
```

Which is perfectly correct. Now, when I read the serial port using  Python I get this:

```
b'20.32\r\n'
b'20.32\r\n'
b'20.32\r\n'
b'20.80\r\n'
...
```

What does that b' ' thing do? How can I treat the string so I just display the numbers correctly?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while True:
   message = ser.readline()
   print(message)
```

Apologies if it's a dumb question but I'm new to Arduino, Python and serial programming :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `b` prefix in Python 3 just means that it is a `bytes` literal. It's not part of the output, that's just telling you the type.

The `\r\n` is a common Carriage-Return and Newline line-ending characters. You can remove that from your string by calling `strip()`.

Since these are floating-point numbers being returned, I'm guessing you're going to want to use them in some way after they are read, too:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while True:
   value = float(ser.readline().strip())
   print 'New value is {0:0.2f}'.format(value)
```

See also:

- [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `decode()` and `strip()` at once.

```
b'20.32\r\n'.decode().strip('\r\n')
```

Will give you:

```
'20.32'
```